# More elegant way to pass two structs to a callback function in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, callback

Let's say I have two typedef'd structs I use constantly in my program to keep track of several things.

```
typedef struct {
   int64_t  data;
} Struct_1

typedef struct {
   int32_t  data;
} Struct_2
```

I need to register a callback function where I can pass some user data:

```
static int callback_function(void *user_data);
```

So I thought about using an structure to pass both structs:

```
typedef struct {
   Struct_1 *struct_1;
   Struct_2 *struct_2;
} Struct_wrapper;

init_module(Struct_1 *struct_1, Struct_2 *struct_2) {

Struct_wrapper struct_wrapper;
struct_wrapper.struct_1 = struct_1;
struct_wrapper.struct_2 = struct_2;

register_callback(callback_function, &struct_wrapper);
}
```

and the callback function unwraps the structs this way:

```
static int callback_function(void *user_data) {

Struct_wrapper *struct_wrapper;
Struct_1 *struct_1;
Struct_2 *struct_2;

struct_wrapper = user_data;

struct_1 = struct_wrapper->struct_1;
struct_2 = struct_wrapper->struct_2;

process_data1(struct_1->data);
process_data2(struct_2->data);

return 0;
}
```

Is that the most elegant solution? Can I 'unwrap' the structs in a different/more efficient way?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Yes, such a wrapper struct would be the common way. But if this is actual code, you have a lifetime issue with `register_callback(callback_function, &struct_wrapper);`, when you return from `init_module()` the `struct_wrapper` variable will be gone/destroyed.

Comment: Matters of opinion are not appropriate for stack overflow. If you have code that works and meets your requirements, you haven't got a problem this site can help with. If you have a problem with your code, you need to be more finite about describing it.

Comment: Yes you are right. Now I see it. What is the recommended way to do it then? The Caller to init_module() is main(). Should I keep the wrapper struct in main or should I declare a static global variable in the module file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a struct is perfectly fine, but seeing as you're passing around pointers to structs, you could just use an array of void pointers, too.
Not sure if you're want to, because it does make for messy code, but just as an example:

```
init_module(Struct_1 *struct_1, Struct_2 *struct_2)
{
    void *wrapper[2] = {
        (void *) struct_1,
        (void *) struct_2
    };
    //to access them again:
    *((Struct_1 *)wrapper[0]).data = 123;
}
```

Note that you *do* need to cast void pointers if you want to dereference them, if not, the compiler will throw up errors, or you might get undefined behaviour in some edge cases (ie doing `offsetof` macro thingies).
A major disadvantage of using arrays here, though, is that you have to *know* which index holds what type, so for your own sake: stick to the `struct`.

Note that, if this is your code, you are passing *a pointer to a local variable* to the `register_callback` function. Once the `init_module` function returns, that local variable is no more, and the pointer passed to `register_callback` points to memory that *"is no more"* (ie, the wrapper could well be gone). Be weary of that, too.

Comment: Thanks for the observation on the lifetime of the struct wrapper. Any recommendation on where to declare the wrapper struct? the Caller to init_module() is main(). Should I keep the wrapper struct in main or should I declare a static global variable in the module file? I always doubt about how to do it...

Comment: @fazineroso: That really depends on how long that callback will need to be there. If the answer to that is: for as long as the program runs, then yes, the wrapper should go in the `main` function, however, passing too many pointers around gets tiresome, so I wouldn't rule out a static global `static struct { Struct_1 * s1; Struct_2 * s2; } *wrapper;` or something like that

Comment: Thanks Elias. What about making declaring the struct Wrapper static inside of the init_module() function? Shouldn't that work also? Is it elegant?

Comment: @fazineroso: it could work, but it's not elegant: the pointers in the wrapper can't be changed once the `init_module` function has been called, and the wrappers lifetime will be the same as that of a global variable from there on end. I'd opt for the global variable in that case